# Where are the security patches for old versions?

Tags: android, android-security

I'm looking at the Android Security Bulletin for January 2018 and finds many issues fixed in Android 7.1.2, but I can't find the exact patch. For instance, CVE-2017-13179 referenced as Android Bug ID: A-66969193 is fixed for android-8.1.0. The fixed is found at the branch android-8.1.0_r46 link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-8.1.0_r46
The exact commit is 47d4b33 found at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/47d4b33b504e14e98420943f771a9aecd6d09516
However, for 7.1.2, the patch cannot be found, even if I'm going to the latest branch of 7.1.2 which is android-7.1.2_r36 found at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-7.1.2_r36

So where is the patch for 7.1.2? Did Google stop patching 7.1.2, if so why do they write 7.1.2 under the "Updated AOSP versions" column of the security bulletin https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2018-01-01

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they just released the missing updates with the `android-7.0.0_r36` tag...